# click on the list item, it toggles the line-through sytle class on and off

Tags: javascript, html, css

**i want to know why i cant use li element in function.**
i.e. 
i have tried this command 
`li.classList.toggle("done")`
but it shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined"`

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++)
{
 li[i].addEventListener("click", function()
 {
  li.classList.toggle("done");
 });
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Shopping List</h1>
 <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
 <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
 <button id="enter">Enter</button>
 <ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo....`li[0].classList.toggle("done");`

Answer (score 1):

That's becuase `li` referes to the HTMLCollection of `<li>` elements, not an individual `<li>` element itself. You need to:

1. use `li[i].classList` **and**
2. use `let` in the for loop, [due to JS closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

So you have something like this, assuming that you only support browsers that supports ES6:

```
const li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  const el = li[i];
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    el.classList.toggle("done");
  });
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to use the `forEach` function instead. Since `getElementsByTagName` does not return an iterator, you are better off using `querySelectorAll`, which there is a `forEach` method available:

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
li.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function () {
    el.classList.toggle("done");
  });
});
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
const li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    li[i].classList.toggle("done");
  });
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<p id="first">Get it done today</p>
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that inside of the anonymous `function` you are out of scope from from your original `for` loop because the code in the function runs on a `click` even that is unrelated to the loop that created it.

You might observe that `li.classList` should have been `li[i].classList` but this won't help.

There are a couple of ways to resolve this but the most reliable way I believe is to use the `event` callback data and use the `target` property.

```js
const li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(let i=0; i<li.length; i++)
{
 li[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  event.target.classList.toggle('done');

 });
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Shopping List</h1>
 <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
 <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
 <button id="enter">Enter</button>
 <ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li><span>Birthday Cake</span></li>
  <li><div>Candles</div></li>
 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wrapped added a couple of child elements to some list items to demonstrate that `target` is the `li` and not the item clicked inside.